# WPML & Events Manager translatable fields after duplication

Tags: translation, events, plugin-wpml

I have created a WordPress site with WPML and Events Manager together. I want to create events in a language and then translate it to my second one. That's easy but I can't seem to find where I change the event location name, address, time aso after I have duplicated an event with WPML. And it is quite important for me to change the location/place name of an event because it spells differently in the two languages that I want to display on my site.

How can I make it possible for me to edit the location name after I have duplicated and begun translating an event with WPML?

Comment: WPML has an [english support forum](https://wpml.org/forums/forum/english-support/), you'll have much better luck of finding an answer to such a specific question there

Answer (score 0):

I found out how I should do it. Just go over to places in the Events Manager settings panel, duplicate & translate the place, then change the place title.